# NPTH through SMD pad

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, surface-mount, kicad, through-hole

I'm trying to incorporate this design for an [18650 battery clip](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/keystone-electronics/254/9646025?s=N4IgTCBcDaIMwDYC0YCsAWJA5AIiAugL5A) into my PCB. I'm using KiCad.

If you look at the datasheet, you'll notice that there's actually two tabs sticking down from both ends of the clip. That would imply that, as a surface mount device, there needs to be matching holes in the SMD pads for the tabs to slide into. Does anyone know how I would design that? I've been trying to use a non-plated through hole that goes through the SMD pad, but as you can see, it's giving me errors. Would I put a Through-Hole inside the SMD pad?

[image]

Any advice would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Does it really matter if the tabs becomes soldered? You could edit the existing SMD pad into a through-hole pad of the same or adjusted size. You can even offset the actual hole if needed to locate the tab correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I would just make a new footprint for the whole thing. This would eliminate the DRC errors you're getting; make sure the pads are assigned to the correct nets after updates from the schematic (which can be a problem manually assigning them in PCB view); ensure correct spacing; and let you put in the courtyard, mask, paste, and silkscreen layers properly.

Edit: you can use the "Shape Offset X" value to move the hole location of a rounded rectangle PTH pad.  I believe this also works for plain rectangular pads but I was having trouble accessing the offset field.

[image: pad]

Answer (score 0):

Is this for one-offs or production?

One-off, I would just as well leave it: use PTH, paste it as usual (maybe block off the area of the hole), and go back over it with a soldering iron later to ensure adequate fillet.

For production, I would consider a paste-in-pad process.

The tab is almost certainly intended to solder, and the footprint will be much weaker without it.